# Report shows blank page in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

My report shows a blank page when I run it. The data table has information, but none of it shows on the page:

[image]

The stored procedure fetches data to data table:

[image]

```
rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
DataTable DTReport = new DataTable();

SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Number", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
param[0].Value = Session["PrintNumber"].ToString();
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@LOTS", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
param[1].Value = Lots.Trim();
DTReport = objdAccess.ExecuteSpDataTable("SPfetch", param);
CrystalReportViewer1.ID = "DeliveryNote-" + Session["PrintNumber"].ToString();
string Report = "~/Reports/Report.rpt";
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Report));
rptDoc.SetDataSource(DTReport);
rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@number", Session["PrintNumber"].ToString());
rptDoc.SetParameterValue("@LOTS", Lots.Trim());

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind(); 
CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Did you try to preview it before running in the browser/app??

Answer (score 0):

I just added "crystalreportviewers13" this folder to my project folder and it solved the issue.